# Circles in Circles problem

Tags: geometry

How many ratio a circle and her in circles.
Example.
Consider a circle $C$ of radius $R$. $n$ smaller circles, all of the same radius, are to be placed inside $C$ in such a way that each of the $n$ smaller circles internally touches $C$ and externally touches two other smaller circles. Given $R$ and a positive integer $n (n > 2)$, you have to find the radius $r$ of the smaller circles.
See the above figure for better understanding.

[See here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2Fimages%2Feps-gif%2FCirclesInCircles_1000.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FCirclePacking.html&docid=XvDtmlyu2Dg2_M&tbnid=YRFQ2mr69_etxM%3A&vet=1&w=366&h=241&client=ms-android-lenovo&bih=452&biw=320&ved=0ahUKEwj87oaE3pfTAhUHqY8KHeecDUAQxiAIFygA&iact=c&ictx=1)

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share any of your ideas/what you've attempted and where you got stuck?

Comment: I get this problem a programming contests hear this problem https://algo.codemarshal.org/problems/556cc7ff7b4cec0300d4abcb

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you connect the centers of the small circles you have a regular polygon.  If you connect the points of tangency between the small circles and the large circle you have a larger regular polygon with the same number of sides.  The side of the small polygon is twice the radius of the small circles.